# Regex: Is it possible to substitute an input string but adjusted as a numerical value?

Tags: regex

Completely new to Regex, been trying to read up on it via Microsoft Learn site, and testing it out at regex101, but I have one problem I can't seem to figure out.

We have an in-house software that register barcodes from a barcode scanner, and adds them to our database. The expected format is 8 numbers + 1813 or 1814. As an built-in function, we can use regex commands (based on the .NET 7.0 version) to capture the input barcode (I tried one such as (^\d{8})(18)(13|14)) and substitute parts of it before adding to the database. In my case, I would like the output to be the same but two less in value, e.g. 1813 -> 1811 or 1814 -> 1812.

Is it possible to do this substitution based on actual numerical values?

Thanks!

Edit: I saw the link to the other question, but I don't believe I can use a command like that with functions. (*String s = Regex.Replace("1239", @"\d", m => (Int32.Parse(m.ToString()) + 1).ToString());*. At least, it doesn't work when I try it out in regex101.com. It looks like I have to set the output in the form of e.g. *$1$2$3* (that would give me the exact same output as the input)

Comment: "*[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)*"